# istio-engressgateway does not work in microk8s

Tags: kubernetes, istio, microk8s

For testing and learning purposes I tried to use `istio` in microk8s.
`microk8s.enable istio`

Then

`export MYHOST=$(microk8s.kubectl config view -o jsonpath={.contexts..namespace}).bookinfo.com`

`microk8s.kubectl apply -l version!=v2,version!=v3 -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.5/samples/bookinfo/platform/kube/bookinfo.yaml`

`microk8s.kubectl get pods` shows running bookinfo containers.

But when I try to get `gateway` it shows me nothing.

`microk8s.kubectl get gateway`

> No resources found in default namespace.

`microk8s.kubectl get all --all-namespaces` shows `pod/istio-engressgateway` and its IP address.

But I can not access to that IP address, it shows not found.

What am I missing here? I just started Kubernetes and microk8s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to get bookinfo sample gateway yaml. To get that you must-

`microk8s.kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.5/samples/bookinfo/networking/bookinfo-gateway.yaml`

That should work..